# Stability of the equilibrium at the origin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the system $\bf{\dot{x}}$=$A_{3x3}$$\bf{x}$ You  are  given  that $A$ is  nonsingular  and  the unstable subspace of $A$ is trivial.  Is this information sufficient to infer the stability of
the equilibrium at the origin?  Explain your reasoning.

## Solution

This information is not sufficient because equilibrium point
$\bf{x}$=$ 0$ of $\bf{\dot{x}}$=$A$$\bf{x}$
is stable if and only if all eigenvalues of $A$ satisty $Re[\lambda_{i}] \leq 0$ and for every eigenvalue with $Re[\lambda_{i}]=0$ and algebraic multiplicity $q_{i} \geq 2$, $rank(A-\lambda_i I)=n-q_i$
where $n$ is the dimension of $\bf{x}$.
I'm not sure if my explanation is right

Comment: Yes, your explanation is fine. Or if you prefer: eigenvalues with zero real part may have nontrivial Jordan canonical forms.